# mutt: bcc to /var/mail/myself instead of out via IMAP?

Tags: email, imap, mutt, bcc

During `mutt -f imaps://imap.example.com/INBOX`, when I send an email, if I bcc to myself, then the bcc gets sent to the inbox at my email provider at example.com.  Then it's an extra step to retrieve that message.

Can I instead bcc directly to my local mail spool, the file `/var/mail/myself`?  Is there a syntax for that?
Even if .muttrc has `my_hdr Bcc: $spoolfile`, it ends up appearing as `Bcc: /var/mail/myself@example.com`.

Ubuntu 22, with its current mutt 2.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bcc:` is the entirely wrong header for storing into a mailbox, whether it's to a file or to IMAP. In both cases you want to use `Fcc:` (file carbon copy) – that's the Mutt mechanism for storing a message into "Sent". Use `set record=` to define the default Fcc value.